# TADOStoredProc/TADOQuery CommandTimeout...?‏

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, timeout, delphi-7

On a client is being raised the error "Timeout" to trigger some commands against the database.

My first test option for correction is to increase the CommandTimeout to 99999  ... but I am afraid that this treatment generates further problems.

Have experienced it ...?
I wonder if my question is relevant, and/or if there is another option more robust and elegant correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to assume that upping the timeout is not the correct approach.  Typically, I look for log running queries that are running around the timeouts.  They will typically stand out in the areas of duration and reads.

Then I'll work to reduce the query run time using this method:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/simple-query-tuning-with-statistics-io-and-execution-plans/

If it's a report causing issues and you can't get it running faster, you may need to start thinking about setting up a reporting database.

Answer (score 0):

CommandTimeout is a time, that the client is waiting for a response from server. If the query is run in the main VCL thread then the whole application is "frozen" and  might be marked "not responding" by Windows. So, would you expect your users to wait at frozen app for 99999 sec?

Generally, leave the Timeout values at default and rather concentrate on tunning the queries as Sam suggests. If you happen to have long running queries (ie. some background data movement,  calculations etc in Stored Procedures) set the CommandTimeout to 0 (=INFINITE) but run them in a separate thread.